# inline-block vertical alignment

Tags: css

I know there are a number of ways to do this, but really looking for a good explanation of why vertical alignment does not work in this case:

http://jsfiddle.net/jasonsnyc/zAg8g/1/

What I am after is centering the images vertically without using floats, tables, or display:table-cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `line-height: 135px;` on the containers, and `vertical-align: middle` on the images themselves.

Comment: That's what I thought originally, but it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/zAg8g/2/

Comment: Well if you completely ignore me saying to use the vertical align on the *image itself*, then of course it won't work...

Comment: Yep, just noticed that. The class name was `.img` and that threw me off: http://jsfiddle.net/zAg8g/3/

Comment: And there you have it: middle-aligned images. Of course, it'd be even easier if you defined them as background images and used `background-position: center center` ;)

Comment: It works perfectly, so thank you Kolink.   I would still love to know the "why" though I don't have the reputation points to compensate for that I believe.  My css skill are ok and this solution would never have occurred to me so there is something I am not understanding.